# MySQL UPDATE from php doesn't... update

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This is the example of what is built under here, apart from the php code: **http://jsfiddle.net/MJU8S/**
Whenever a field is edited, if enter is pressed it should be sent the update to the database. The problem is that nothing is sent at all.

How can I fix this mess? Is it even possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(){
        var input = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        input.removeAttribute("disabled");
        input.focus();
        input.addEventListener("keypress", save, false);
    }

    function save(e){
        if (e.type == "keypress" && e.keyCode != 13)
            return;
        this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        /*removed*/document.cookie = "variable=" + this.getAttribute("name");
        /*removed*/document.cookie = "value=" + this.getAttribute("value");
        /*removed*/document.cookie = "id=" + this.getAttribute("id");
        /*removed*/
        <?php
            $variable = $_COOKIE["variable"];
            $value = $_COOKIE["value"];
            $id = $_COOKIE["id"];
            mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
            @mysql_select_db($database) or die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.alert('Errore nella connessione al database: salvataggio interrotto.');</script>");
            $update_query = "UPDATE Serie SET `$variable`='$value' WHERE `id`='$id'";
            mysql_query($update_query) or die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.alert('Errore nella query: salvataggio interrotto.');</script>");
            mysql_close();
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

---

You are quite severe with reputation points, aren't you? =P Btw...

**EDIT**: Thanks for the lessons, it's the first time I do something for the web. If I understood correctly, I need Ajax to do something without refresh, something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(){
        var input = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        input.removeAttribute("disabled");
        input.focus();
        input.addEventListener("keypress", save, false);
    }

    function save(e){
        if (e.type == "keypress" && e.keyCode != 13)
            return;
        this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        /*new*/var value = this.getAttribute("value");
        /*new*/if(value == "" || value == null)
        /*new*/ return;
        /*new*/ var variable = this.getAttribute("name");
        /*new*/ var id = this.getAttribute("id");
        /*new*/ xmlhttp.open("POST","update_query.php",true);
        /*new*/ xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        /*new*/ xmlhttp.send("variable="+variable+"&value="+value+"&id="+id);
    }
</script>
```

And then I'm suppose to put in the "update_query.php" this connection:

```
<?php
    $variable = $_POST["variable"];
    $value = $_POST["value"];
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.alert('Errore nella connessione al database: salvataggio interrotto.');</script>");
    $update_query = "UPDATE Serie SET $variable='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($update_query) or die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.alert('Errore nella query: salvataggio interrotto.');</script>");
    mysql_close();
?>
```

---

<del>Nope, it still doesn't work...</del>

**EDIT**: I was getting some value wrongly.

```
function save(e){
    if (e.type == "keypress" && e.keyCode != 13)
        return;
    this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    /*new*/var value = e.target.value;
    if(value == "" || value == null)
        return;
    /*new*/ var variable = e.target.name;
    /*new*/ var id = e.target.id;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","update_query.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("variable="+variable+"&value="+value+"&id="+id);
}
```

Comment: why are you using cookie to update?

Comment: can you please take a look into html code which you actually see in browser (usually right-click view source) and find the php part in it

Comment: I read somewhere that coockies were the only way to send a value from JS to PHP... Well, nevermind, it was all wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either

- AJAX if you dont want the page to refresh. If that's the case check out http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first. You gotta pass the edited value to another php page which will do the database operations for you. Javascript is a client-side technology which will do operations mainly on the browser. PHP is a server-side technology that will work on the resources on the server. It seems like you have misunderstood them.
- The simplest way is to simply post the values with out ajax.

Comment: Does the backend php page gets called? You can check this from the javascript console in FF or Chrome. I think IE has such tool as well. Let us know if it get's called or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just put a block of PHP code in the middle of a JavaScript and expect it to work like you have in your question example.

The PHP code in your question will run, once, on the server, when the page is being requested - the code will not reach the browser, and if you "view source" of your page in your browser, you will not see anything after the line `document.cookie = "id=" + this.getAttribute("id");`

In order to make your JavaScript function save to a database the way you seem to want it to, you will need to send the data via an AJAX request to a server-side PHP script which will then take that data and save it.

Otherwise - a simple form POST would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem:

```
    document.cookie = "variable=" + this.getAttribute("name");
    document.cookie = "value=" + this.getAttribute("value");
    document.cookie = "id=" + this.getAttribute("id");
```

What you are doing is rewriting document.cookie every time you use `=`. The working code to set cookie should be:

```
    document.cookie = "variable=" + encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute("name"));
    document.cookie += ";value=" + encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute("value"));
    document.cookie += ";id=" + encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute("id"));
```

Where `+=` appends the next cookie value, and `";` adds a semicolon, required to separate cookie `key1=value1;key2=value2` pairs.
Also, cookies must be encoded with `encodeURIComponent`. See http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml for more information.